# Log Authentication Events with Microsoft.Identity.Web in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, microsoft-identity-web

I'm trying to work out how to configure logging Authentication events that occur is MicrosoftIdentityWeb in ASP.NET Core 6.0 and I'm having trouble finding a simple example.

My code is currently the .net60 template code, I've tried to follow previous examples to add logging, but I can't get it to work correctly:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

IConfiguration opt = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    // Was: .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        // Handle Auth events and bind Configuration here somehow?
    });

...
```

How can I bind the configuration and subscribe to the authentication events so I can see why my authentication is failing and log auth attempts for security purposes?

Comment: Do post how you have tried to configure logging so far.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to follow [this](https://blog.datalust.co/using-serilog-in-net-6/) blog post to add logging to your application.

Then you need to tweak the login levels like this:

```
.MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
.MinimumLevel.Override("IdentityServer4", LogEventLevel.Information)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection", LogEventLevel.Debug)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization", LogEventLevel.Information);
```

See the source code sample here for more details:

- [net6.0 Serilog example](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example)

If this is not enough, you can get even more details by using the System.Diagnostics.Tracing sub-system that on Windows will send data to Event Tracing for Windows (ETW).